# Singularity image size and internal disk usage ( du ) mismatch

Tags: containers, singularity-container

I wanted to ask for clarification regarding disk usage ( du ) within a singularity image and the apparent mismatch I'm seeing.

For example:

If I list the container image information:

```
ls -s --block-size=M container.sif
428M container.sif
```

The image size is as displayed.

But if I check on a directory within which is neither mounted nor bound to the container and was created in the build stage I get the following result.

```
singularity exec container.sif du -sh /src
1.4G    /src
```

The total disk usage of the container when checked from within is over 4.4G. I assumed this was due to files within my home directory that are bound but now I'm not so sure.

Why is there a mismatch?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

The [Singularity image format (SIF)](https://docs.sylabs.io/guides/3.10/user-guide/security.html#singularity-image-format-sif) uses [SquashFS](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/squashfs.html), a compressed file system. This lets the image be bigger on the inside, and smaller on the host disk. It's part of why singularity images are smaller* than the docker images they're built from.

*e.g.,*

```bash
docker pull ubuntu:22.04
# 22.04: Pulling from library/ubuntu
# 2b55860d4c66: Pull complete 
# ...

docker image ls ubuntu:22.04
# REPOSITORY   TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED        SIZE
# ubuntu       22.04     2dc39ba059dc   38 hours ago   77.8MB

singularity pull docker://ubuntu:22.04
# INFO:    Converting OCI blobs to SIF format
# INFO:    Starting build...
# ... 

du -h ubuntu_22.04.sif 
# 29M   ubuntu_22.04.sif
```

`*`: Docker also stores layer information that singularity does not and can reach similar sizes if exported (via `docker save`) and gzipped. They still must be expanded and loaded again to be used, though.